# Regex overly splitting, how to limit split character

Tags: regex

***Edited as originally posted at 2am after much frustration. Tidied up.***

I'm currently trying to split a string into sections where each array entry starts and ends at == or end-of-string. String should always start with == and terminate with out any special char's at the end. Developing in Angular so code will be TS.

Example text `==key stage 4==\n===meaning===\n'''visible light''' is an [[electromagnetic wave|electromagnetic wave]] that [[human]]s can see.\n\n===about light===\n====properties====\n: '''visible light''' is a [[transverse wave|transverse wave]].\n: '''visible light''' can travel through a [[vacuum]] as well as through any [[transparent]] [[solid]], [[liquid]], [[gas]].\n: the [[speed]] of '''visible light''' through a [[vacuum]] is 300,000,000[[m/s]].\nas a [[wave]] [[light]] can be:\n*[[transmit|transmitted]]\n\n==beyond the curriculum==\n{{#ev:youtube|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixxzrzxafeq}}`

Needs to be split into:

1.
`==key stage 4==\n===meaning===\n'''visible light''' is an [[electromagnetic wave|electromagnetic wave]] that [[human]]s can see.\n\n===about light===\n====properties====\n: '''visible light''' is a [[transverse wave|transverse wave]].\n: '''visible light''' can travel through a [[vacuum]] as well as through any [[transparent]] [[solid]], [[liquid]], [[gas]].\n: the [[speed]] of '''visible light''' through a [[vacuum]] is 300,000,000[[m/s]].\nas a [[wave]] [[light]] can be:\n*[[transmit|transmitted]]\n\n`

2.
`==beyond the curriculum==\n{{#ev:youtube|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixxzrzxafeq}}`

I've tried all manner of expressions.

Currently trying: `var h2reOuter = /(?===[w+b(?<!=]*==)/gm;` with little success. I've also tried `var h2reOuter = /(?===[^=]*==)/gm;`

Using `result = str.split(h2reOuter);`

But its resulting in splitting on '====' which is not valid.

Once done I will also need to search for the text inside the ==Text==. The above expression does work for this. This swaps in `<h2>#</h2>` for ==#== and `<h3>#</h3>` for ===#===. Got this working okay but added for context.

Any advice?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using a programming language here?

Comment: Can you minimize the input and output text? It's pretty much unreadable. Is this JS?

Comment: Try: `var h2reOuter = /(?<===)[^=]+(?===)/gm;`  `+` requires at least one character between the equal signs.

Comment: @Poul Bak that will not solve OP's problem, will still match ===. Perhaps `(?<=^|[^=])==[\w\s]+==(?=[^=])` instead

Comment: *surely* you can create a vastly smaller test case that demonstrates the problem. Your test case is tldr material. Please aggressively edit your sample input and output down to the bare minimum, and add explanation as to the logic of exactly what constitutes the desired split locations.

Comment: @jdaz: `[\w\s]+` will not match the special characters, you must use: `[^=]+`.

Comment: Try to split using this regex: `/(?<=\\n\\n)==(?!=)/g`  - That will split on 2 *newlines* followed by 2 equal signs. This seems to be what you really want.

Comment: Use `str.split(/\n{2,}==(?!=)/)`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65554918/11329890

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
str.split(/\n{2,}==(?!=)/)
```

**Explanation**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \n{2,}                   '\n' (newline) (at least 2 times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ==                       '=='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    =                        '='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

**JavaScript code**:

```js
const str = "==key stage 4==\n===meaning===\n'''visible light''' is an [[electromagnetic wave|electromagnetic wave]] that [[human]]s can see.\n\n===about light===\n====properties====\n: '''visible light''' is a [[transverse wave|transverse wave]].\n: '''visible light''' can travel through a [[vacuum]] as well as through any [[transparent]] [[solid]], [[liquid]], [[gas]].\n: the [[speed]] of '''visible light''' through a [[vacuum]] is 300,000,000[[m/s]].\nas a [[wave]] [[light]] can be:\n*[[transmit|transmitted]]\n\n==beyond the curriculum==\n{{#ev:youtube|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixxzrzxafeq}}"
console.log(str.split(/\n{2,}==(?!=)/))
```

Answer (score 0):

Split on `==` after 2 new lines and not before a `=`:

```
(?<=\n\n)==(?!=)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/oKeCiXbq69nUju).

Note: If `\n` in your input is *not* a new line but a backslash then `n`, you’ll need to escape the backslashes:

```
(?<=\\n\\n)==(?!=)
```